C# Windows - DataGridViewComboBoxCell not being cleared from a DataGridView
I'm using VS 2022 C# Windows.
I have a DataGridView that will display a DataGridViewComboBoxCell, depending on the col selected.
    private void dgv_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Not Form Just Loaded and CurrentCell Not Null
        if ((!Form_Just_Loaded) && (dgv.CurrentCell != null))
        {
            int Col = dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
            int Row = dgv.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

            switch (Col)
            {
                case Con_Day_Of_Week_Col:
                    {
                        // If the Focus is in the Day of The week Column then set to the next Cell
                        break;
                    }   
                case Con_Company_Col:
                    {
                        // If the Focus is in the Company Name Column then create the combobox and display
                        DataGridViewComboBoxCell myCell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dgvTimeSheet.Rows[Row].Cells[Col];
                        myCell.Items.Clear();
                        for (int m = 0; m < Con_Companys.Length; m++)
                        {
                            myCell.Items.Add(Con_Companys[m]);
                        }
                        // Open the Combobox
                        SendKeys.Send("{F4}");
                        break;
                    }
            }                   
        }
    }

This works fine.
When clearing a row, the DataGridViewComboBoxCell is still visible, and doesn't work when using a ContextMenuStrip|ToolStripMenuItem.
    private void tsmiClear_Row_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int Selected_Row = dgvTimeSheet.CurrentRow.Index;

        for (int i = Con_Normal_Hours_Col; i < dgvTimeSheet.ColumnCount; i++)
        {
            dgvTimeSheet.Rows[Selected_Row].Cells[i].Value = "";
        }
    }

If I call the ContextMenuStrip|ToolStripMenuItem event from a Button it works, clears the DataGridViewComboBoxCell.
    private void btnClear_Row_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tsmiClear_Row_Click(sender, e);
    }

Why does the DataGridViewComboBoxCell get cleared if I use the button event and not when using the ContextMenuStrip|ToolStripMenuItem event?
Thanks

As for the CMS, you need to select a Row in order to the grid's CurrentRow property returns it. If you want to get an unselected Row at the mouse position, then you need to do something like this. See also DataGridView.HitTest method.

Hi dr.null. The "dgvTimeSheet.CurrentRow.Index" is the row. This is proven as all DataGridView cells will be cleared (within the bounds of the loop) EXCEPT if the DataGridViewComboBoxCell is still visible AND tsmiClear_Row_Click( event fired from the ContextMenuStrip|ToolStripMenuItem).  The btnClear_Row_Click( event will clear all cells and the DataGridViewComboBoxCell if its still visible.

The only way I've found is to set the focus on the DataGridView to a cell that's on the same row but is not the DataGridViewComboBoxCell.
private void tsmiClear_Row_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int Selected_Row = dgvTimeSheet.CurrentRow.Index;
    
    dgvTimeSheet.Rows[Selected_Row].Cells[Con_Normal_Hours_Col].Selected = true;
    
    for (int i = Con_Normal_Hours_Col; i < dgvTimeSheet.ColumnCount; i++)
    {
        dgvTimeSheet.Rows[Selected_Row].Cells[i].Value = "";
    }
}

